# how i can find ordim.jar for my java project?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, java

i didn't find ordim.jar for my java project to manipuate Multimedia object " Type ORDSource type and OrdMediaUtil class" using oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my 11g, it is located in

```
D:\oracle11\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\ord\jlib
```

directory.